# Custom taxonomy Rewrite Rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want my taxonomy url to be like this: site.com/page/taxonomy_term

How will I be able to achieve this? I have written a wordpress rewrite rule code in my functions.php like this:

```
function sphere_custom_rewrite_rules( $rules ){
    $newrules['(.+?)/([^/]*)/?'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&positive_sphere=$matches[2]';
    $newrules['(.+?)/([^/]*)/?'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&negative_sphere=$matches[2]';

    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'sphere_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

the page doesn't return 404 error, but it doesn't do my functions in taxonomy.php instead it's doing my code on my template-page-name.php file. What I want is when I types this url:

site.com/page/taxonomy_term it'll run my code on taxonomy.php.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 of Wordpress' built in functions to get the result you're after.

add_rewrite_tag() and add_rewrite_rule()

There is an example of how to use these tags to get the result you want about halfway down this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule.

Note: remember to flush your rewrite rules.